# Google Gadget for slideshow

Tags: google-slides, gadget

I'd like a recommendation for a Google Gadget that displays a Google Presentation without borders nor the bottom menu.

The default gadget for embedding a Google Presentation always ends up with a bottom menu. Not great for marketing on a company web site.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately users are not able to remove the bar from the bottom of presentations:

[Source Article from Google FAQ](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=2401b982977279e5&hl=en)

You can customise a Gadget to alter the height so you can hide the tool bar - full instructions on how to do this [can be found here](http://sites.google.com/site/mori79/html-gadgets/how-tos/embed-docs#TOC-Presentations).